# Newest version of chrome CSS issue

Tags: css, google-chrome

Has anyone noticed a change to the rendering in the latest Chrome on Windows (22.0.1229.94 m)?

On page

http://worldwide.espacenet.com/

we had until recently (and have in IE8/9, FX16/17, Safari 5)

[image]

and in Chrome (22.0.1229.94 m):

[image]

The CSS starts with `YUI Reset CSS version: 2.5.1`

Here is the relevant html

```
<div class="epoBar epoBarAction">
  <div class="secondary">
    <div class="epoBarItem">
      <a href="javascript:clearFormContents(document.searchForm);">Clear</a>
    </div>
    <div class="epoBarItem epoBarItemForm">
      <div class="formElement">
        <span class="inputsubmit">
          <input type="submit" class="submit" name="Submit" value="Search">
        </span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Weird behaviour:** If I inspect element and toggle the `float:left` below twice, the buttons align as they should

```
div.epoBar div.epoBarItem {
  float: left;
  min-height: 1.67em;
  padding-bottom: 0.42em;
}
```

Also if I add `width:150px` to the div with class="secondary", it also aligns.

Is there anything obviously weird or is there a known new bug I have missed in Chrome?

Hope someone will be so kind and inspect the page

Comment: yes ,google chrome sucks ... always.. it have always issue in padding and margin

Comment: Don't you use a reset style sheet to make all browsers set basic values to be the same?

Comment: Yes, if you look, the first CSS contains /**
 * YUI Reset CSS version: 2.5.1

Answer (score 0):

### Font rendering

Google chrome renders fonts differently to other browsers on windows to allow it to install without needing admin privileges. A pain, I know, but they outweigh ease of install over needing admin rights for antialiasing. That said, the font may be overflowing the width of the container you are putting it in, and should fixable by adding a larger width to the container, or removing it entirely. Also using ems rather than px will give different font sizes across browsers.

Comment: But this worked in the last version of Chrome as far as we know